# tuple one number with list of numbers python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Suppose I have a number `15` and list of numbers:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Now I want to make a list of tuples like

```
[(15,6), (15,5), (15,7), (15,8)]
```

How does one do that quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_of_nums = [5, 6, 7, 8]
result = [(15, num) for num in list_of_nums]
```

Whenever you have a process producing a list based on the output of another sequence, *usually* a list comprehension can do the job.

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_nums = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> [(15, num) for num in list_of_nums]
[(15, 5), (15, 6), (15, 7), (15, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `zip` function

```
result = zip([15]*len(list_of_nums),list_of_nums)

print(result)
[(15, 5), (15, 6), (15, 7), (15, 8)]
```